Looking to copy value down across blank cells until it hits another non blank value
I feel like I'm close, but I'm looking to solving this, but I'm trying to generate an output that looks like the preferred output tab (so student 1 next to each of their classes and the code next to that class). Compounding issues, students could be taking anywhere from 1 class, to 5.
Data comes like this:

Ideally the data should ignore empty lines between data sets and output like this:

Using some interwebz searching I think the solution might be related to a vlookup and row arrays, but my indices on the lookup aren't really outputting what i want
Here's a sample portion of the sheet with names obfuscated.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Choose Insert > Sheet and put this formula in cell A1 of the new sheet:
=let( 
  fillDown_, lambda(data, let(a,data,r,max(bycol(a,lambda(l,index(ifna(xmatch("?*",to_text(l),2,-1)))))),s,sequence(r),array_constrain(bycol(a,lambda(v,map(s,lambda(i,index(xlookup(i,s/(v<>""),v,,-1)))))),r,columns(a)))), 

  data, filter('working concepts'!A1:C, len('working concepts'!B1:B)), 

  fillDown_(data) 
)

See
let(),
lambda(),
bycol(),
index(),
xmatch(),
xlookup(),
map(),
sequence(),
and
filter().

=LET(
   arr,FILTER(A:C, LEN(B:B)),
 { SCAN(,INDEX(arr,,1), LAMBDA(a,v, 
     IF(LEN(v),v,a))), 
   CHOOSECOLS(arr,2,3) })

CHOOSECOLS  FILTER  IF  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEN  LET  SCAN
The formula returns a 3-column array where the 1st column is calculated using  SCAN to repeat student names until a new one is encountered.

arr stores an array of columns A to C after removing blank rows using FILTER.
SCAN passes the first column of arr into a LAMBDA, value-by-value, which stores the current value in v.
The LAMBDA's formula checks if v contains a value using LEN.

If it does, that means a new student name has been encountered and v is returned, which also updates the accumulator a to match.
If v is empty, that means the current student hasn't changed, so the accumulator a value is returned, and a remains unchanged.
this is repeated until all v have been processed.


Finally the result of SCAN is returned in addition to the 2nd and 3rd columns from arr using CHOOSECOLS.

